# Привязка к статическому идексатору

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня возникла проблема с привязкой статического свойства в XAML.
Руководствовался данным [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428015/8494155).
В классе у меня определена статическая переменная:

```
class Worker
{
    public static ObservableCollection<int> CountInDirections { get; set; }
    static Worker()
    {
        CountInDirections = new ObservableCollection<int>
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        };
    }
}
```

Но в XAML коде появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Член "CountInDirections[6]" не распознан или недоступен.
```

Вот что в XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=(local:Worker.CountInDirections[6])}"/>
```

Ошибка появляется при обращении по индексу.

Как исправить?

Comment: у класса `Worker` уровень доступа случайно не `private`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder уровень доступа public. С привязкой не статичных свойств проблем нет.

Comment: Вы из 8 ответов выбрали то что с минимальным рейтингом. Почему не выбрали ответ, отмеченный галочкой? Он прекрасно работает

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот честно пробовал, но там у меня другая ошибка была. При запуске программа вылетала с ошибкой: System.NullReferenceException. А в XAML для <local:Worker x:Key="WorkerQ"/> была ошибка: Тип "Worker" не включает каких-либо доступных конструкторов. Хотя в классе Worker есть конструкторы.

Comment: Конструктора без параметров нет?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я затупил под вечер=) в общем спасибо, проблема решена!)

Comment: Напишите ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
{Binding Path=(local:Worker.CountInDirections)[6]}
```

Comment: У меня все три варианта работают одинаково (и реагируют на изменения коллекции), но именно этот вариант не отображается в дизайнере VS

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Странно, у меня они выглядят одинаково.

Comment: @VladD спасибо! Именно то, что мне и надо было.

Answer (score 3):

Для доступа по индексу к статичной коллекции при привязки следует воспользоваться следующим способом:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Worker x:Key="WorkerQ"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkerQ}, Path=CountInDirections[6]}"/>
```

Comment: @VladD, а с индексатором точно сработает?

Comment: @VladD спасибо, потом проверю

Comment: среагирует ли такая привязка на изменение свойства?

Comment: @VladD, к сожалению с индексатором не работает. Попробовал через x:static + converter + converterparameter, работает, но увы на изменение свойства не реагирует. Вижу только одно решение: подписка на собственное событие при изменении статической коллекции и ее дальнейшее копирование

Comment: @Gardes не среагирует(

Comment: @handy: Хм. И правда, с индексатором выходит не очень. У меня вышло так: `{Binding .[6], Source={x:Static local:Worker.CountInDirections}}`. Изменения подхватываются.

Comment: @Gardes: У меня вроде работает, см. комментарий выше.

Comment: @Gardes, код из этого ответа у меня реагирует на изменения типа таких `Worker.CountInDirections[6]++`, GUI обновляется нормально