# Изменение статического свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

На вопрос подтолкнули ответы из [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/783548/204383). Изменения элементов статического списка и вправду подхватываются, но что насчет изменения не элемента, а статического свойства? Такой трюк уже не проходит, изменения не подхватываются:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ., Source={x:Static local:MainVM.Number}}"/>
```

код:

```
static int number = 10;
public static int Number
{
    get { return number; }
    set { number = value; /*OnNumberChanged();*/ }
}
```

Выходом из ситуации вижу создание статического события ("*имя свойства*" + постфикс *"Changed"*):

```
public static event EventHandler NumberChanged;
static void OnNumberChanged()
{
    if (NumberChanged != null)
    {
        NumberChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

и привязываться так:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Number}"/>
```

Вопросы:

- Почему принята именно такая нотация названия события  ("*имя свойства*" + постфикс *"Changed"*), где можно узнать подробнее об этом?
- Как обойтись без создания таких событий на каждое свойство, чтобы подхватывались изменения?

Comment: К статике, к сожалению, INPC не прикрутить, поэтому только `{Property}Changed`. Кстати, `{Property}Changed` работает и для нестатических свойств

Comment: 2. можно же реализовать универсальный `public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged; `, вроде. Надо проверять / UPD: У меня не сработало, почему-то...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Да, про универсальный event слышал, но почему изменение элемента в коллекции подхватывается без использования всего этого?

Comment: Ну как же, у нас же имеется экземпляр этой коллекции, а он реализует внутри INCC... Т.е. здесь именно INCC срабатывает, магии нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP, по ссылке в начале вопроса в коллекции набор значений типа int, никакой реализации INPC нет.

Comment: не INPC, а IN*C*C - Collection. Сама ObservableCollection реализует внутри INCC

Comment: @АндрейNOP, почти было поверил вам) хорошо, я поменял ObservableCollection на List, тот не реализует INCC, и все равно происходит магия...

Comment: Неа, не могу воспроизвести с List, вы что-то не то делаете

Comment: @АндрейNOP, прошу прощения, в ходе проверки выяснилось что я смотрел не на то свойство...

Answer (score 0):

Нотация названия события ("имя свойства" + постфикс "Changed") является стандартной практикой в разработке на платформе .NET для оповещения о изменении свойств. Это соглашение позволяет облегчить чтение и понимание кода, а также обеспечить единообразие в именовании событий.

Когда свойство изменяется, вызывается соответствующее событие "имя свойства" + "Changed". Например, для свойства "Number" вызывается событие "NumberChanged". Это позволяет классам-подписчикам (например, элементам пользовательского интерфейса), которые хотят отслеживать изменения свойств, подписаться на эти события и реагировать на них.

Такой подход упрощает реализацию привязок данных и обновление элементов пользовательского интерфейса при изменении свойств. Когда свойство изменяется, событие срабатывает, и привязанные элементы пользовательского интерфейса автоматически обновляются.

Чтобы избежать необходимости создания таких событий для каждого свойства, можно воспользоваться более продвинутыми средствами привязки данных в WPF, такими как реализация интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged. Этот интерфейс позволяет классу оповестить о изменении своих свойств, и тогда элементы пользовательского интерфейса, привязанные к этим свойствам, будут автоматически обновляться.

Вот пример, как можно использовать INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static int number = 10;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if (number != value)
            {
                number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Number));
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

В этом примере класс MainVM реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Когда свойство Number изменяется, вызывается метод OnPropertyChanged, который оповещает о изменении свойства. Затем элементы пользовательского интерфейса, привязанные к свойству Number, автоматически обновляются.

Используя INotifyPropertyChanged, вы можете избежать создания событий для каждого свойства и обеспечить более эффективное управление изменениями и обновлениями в вашем приложении.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)